# php how to get same values and put it into another array

Tags: php

I searched the net but could not find any solution to my problem.
my question is:

1-How to get array with the same values and put it into another array my array is:

2-How can I get total of gross invoice amount with same tax_due_date, means add the values of gross invoice amount with the same date and put it into one variable.

```
 Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [gross_invoice_amount] => 10000
        [tax_due_date] => 2014-04-04
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [gross_invoice_amount] => 4000
        [tax_due_date] => 2014-09-04
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [gross_invoice_amount] => 1000000
        [tax_due_date] => 2011-04-04
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [gross_invoice_amount] => 100000
        [tax_due_date] => 2014-04-04
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [gross_invoice_amount] => 30000
        [tax_due_date] => 2014-04-04
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [gross_invoice_amount] => 50000
        [tax_due_date] => 2014-04-04
    )

)
```

My question is how can I get the array with same dates and put it into another array means divide it
into chunks.

Comment: `$other_array['foo'] = $your_array[4]['gross_invoice_amount']; // 3000`. Learn how this works, then the actual "find same values" business should be easy.

Comment: How do you want to divide it into chunks?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Do you mean divide the initial array in more arrays grouped by dates?

Comment: I think he wants to get total of gross invoice amounts with the same dates

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how exactly you want to divide it into chunks, but to go through whole array and access data stored in it, use `foreach`:

```
$gross_invoice_amounts = array();
$tax_due_dates = array();

foreach ($myArray as $value)
{
   $gross_invoice_amounts[] = $value['gross_invoice_amount'];
   $tax_due_dates[] = $value['tax_due_date'];
}
```

Foreach will loop whole array (`$myArray`) and current value will be stored in `$value` in this case (you can also use `$key => $value` to access current key too). Inside the loop, you can store values in separated arrays (`[]` is there to assign it to next free position).

Answer (score 0):

First code block below. What it does, it gets all records with the same due date into one array `$new_array`. And that variable contains or will contain 2 dimensional array.

First dimension contains the different due dates and on each of those contains array of the records we put in.

```
$main_array; // let's say, everything is stored here
$new_array = array(); // we will use this to store our grouped data

foreach($main_array as $data)
{
    $new_array[$data['tax_due_date']][] = $data;
}
```

To calculate total sum for each due date:

```
foreach($new_array as $due => $datas)
{
    $count = 0;
    for($i = 0; $i < count($datas); $i++)
    {
        $count += $datas[$i]['gross_invoice_amount'];
    }
    echo "Total Amount Due for the date $due: ".$count;
}
```